# Cannot create custom toolbar button that works on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, photoswipe

I have the simple code:

```
 <button class="pswp__button" id="CustomButton" style="background:none;" title="Custom" onclick="CustomClicked()">
    <img src="~/CustomImage.jpg"">
 </button>
```

This works as expected on desktop browsers.  When I switch to mobile though, I cannot get the event to fire when I tap the button.  I've tried attaching every event handler I can think of: tap, click, touch, touchstart, etc, and I can still not get any of the events to fire on mobile.

If I invoke the click event through the console, it works on mobile as well, but I can't seem to get the click event to propagate to that control.  I've tried setting its zindex to ridiculous values, and still no luck.  Anyone have a clue?

After searching for some solutions online, they all seem to have teh same problem.  This one, for instance, doesn't fire on mobile either:

```js
var openPhotoSwipe = function() {
    var pswpElement = document.querySelectorAll('.pswp')[0];

    // build items array
    var items = [
        {
            src: 'https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1043/5186867718_06b2e9e551_b.jpg',
            w: 964,
            h: 1024
        },
        {
            src: 'https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6175/6176698785_7dee72237e_b.jpg',
            w: 1024,
            h: 683
        }
    ];
    
    // define options (if needed)
    var options = {
    // history & focus options are disabled on CodePen        
       history: false,
       focus: false,

        showAnimationDuration: 0,
        hideAnimationDuration: 0
        
    };
    
    var gallery = new PhotoSwipe( pswpElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, items, options);
    gallery.init();
};

openPhotoSwipe();

$(document).on('click', '.pswp__button.pswp__button--close' , function(){
  alert('d'); // did not fire?
});

document.getElementById('btn').onclick = openPhotoSwipe;
```

```html
<button id="btn">Open PhotoSwipe</button>

<!-- Root element of PhotoSwipe. Must have class pswp. -->
<div class="pswp" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">

    <!-- Background of PhotoSwipe. 
         It's a separate element, as animating opacity is faster than rgba(). -->
    <div class="pswp__bg"></div>

    <!-- Slides wrapper with overflow:hidden. -->
    <div class="pswp__scroll-wrap">

        <!-- Container that holds slides. PhotoSwipe keeps only 3 slides in DOM to save memory. -->
        <div class="pswp__container">
            <!-- don't modify these 3 pswp__item elements, data is added later on -->
            <div class="pswp__item"></div>
            <div class="pswp__item"></div>
            <div class="pswp__item"></div>
        </div>

        <!-- Default (PhotoSwipeUI_Default) interface on top of sliding area. Can be changed. -->
        <div class="pswp__ui pswp__ui--hidden">

            <div class="pswp__top-bar">

                <!--  Controls are self-explanatory. Order can be changed. -->

                <div class="pswp__counter"></div>

                <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--close" title="Close (Esc)"></button>

                <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--share" title="Share"></button>

                <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--fs" title="Toggle fullscreen"></button>

                <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--zoom" title="Zoom in/out"></button>

                <!-- Preloader demo http://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/yyBWoR -->
                <!-- element will get class pswp__preloader--active when preloader is running -->
                <div class="pswp__preloader">
                    <div class="pswp__preloader__icn">
                      <div class="pswp__preloader__cut">
                        <div class="pswp__preloader__donut"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="pswp__share-modal pswp__share-modal--hidden pswp__single-tap">
                <div class="pswp__share-tooltip"></div> 
            </div>

            <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--arrow--left" title="Previous (arrow left)">
            </button>

            <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--arrow--right" title="Next (arrow right)">
            </button>

            <div class="pswp__caption">
                <div class="pswp__caption__center"></div>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve this functionality, you must edit hte photoswipe-ui-default.js file.

Your custom button must have the class pswp__button--myCustomButtonName as well as pswp__button.

```
<button class="pswp__button pswp__button--myCustomButtonName" id="CustomButton" style="background:none;" title="Custom" onclick="CustomClicked()">
<img src="~/CustomImage.jpg"">
```

Inside the photoswipe-ui-default.js file, you'll see a list of controls:

```
var _uiElements = [
    { 
        name: 'caption', 
        option: 'captionEl',
        onInit: function(el) {  
            _captionContainer = el; 
        } 
    },
    { 
        name: 'myCustomButton', 
        option: 'customOptionName',

        onTap:MyCustomButtonFunction
    },
```

You must then add that button name to the options:

```
 var options = {
                        history: false,
                        escKey: false,
                        closeOnScroll: false,
                        pinchToClose: false,
                        closeOnVerticalDrag: false,
                        customOptionName: true
                    };
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without altering the ui elements file? I can't mess around that file for my project.

Comment: Why not it's open source!  The only other way would to inject the element with jquery, but the function that handles the button bar clicks is a big switch statement, so you'd have to get clicks to hit your element and not the button bar.  It's honestly easier to modify their code a little bit I think.

Comment: It would definitely be easier, yeah. I can't change the file because potentially other people will be installing it via bower and then they won't have the altered file. So I need another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use `:before` to apply additional styles to the buttons, or modify the default UI JS file, so it registers click on image too.

By default, it registers tap only on the target element (in your case it's image), and does not propagate up in the DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a way that doesn't involve altering the library. It's just a bit unfortunate the way the click handling is written, since you cannot use preventDefault or stopPropagation to cancel the handler.

```
// Disable hiding controls when tapping action buttons
pswp.framework.bind(pswp.scrollWrap, 'pswpTap', (e) => {
  let el = e.target || e.srcElement;
  while ((el = el.parentElement) && !el.classList.contains('action'));
  if (el) {
    pswp.options.tapToToggleControls = false;
    setTimeout(() => {
      pswp.options.tapToToggleControls = true;
    }, 50);
  }
});
```